# Set Display:block by default for a slideshow

Tags: css, xslt, picture-library

I'm using a picture library to display ppt slides inside a Slideshow presentation. It looks like this:
[image: One slide inside the Slideshow]

Now my problem is that the first slide is always set on Display:none and I have to click first the next button in order to see the first slide. It looks like this:
[image]

My xsl looks like this:

```
    <xsl:template match="/" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/sites/3711/SiteAssets/src/css/presentation.css"/>
    <script src="/sites/3711/SiteAssets/src/js/slideshow.js"></script>
    <div class="slideshow-container">
    <!-- Defining variable userd for all records from a Links list -->
    <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row" />

    <!-- Display the list as a unsorted list. Also you can choose to create a table. -->    

    <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
            <xsl:variable name="LinkFilename">
                <xsl:value-of select="@FileLeafRef"/>
            </xsl:variable> 

            <xsl:variable name="numbertext">
                <xsl:value-of select="@numbertext"/>    
            </xsl:variable>
            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="numbertext"><xsl:value-of select="$numbertext"/></div>
                <img src="/sites/3711/academies/financeacademy/OverviewPresentation/{$LinkFilename}" style="width:100%"/>
            </div>

    </xsl:for-each>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>   
<!-- EOF -->
```

And this is the js I'm using

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

I created the slideshow based on following site:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

Thank you for your help!